# How do I transform large number of similar strings into unique hashes

Tags: string, hash, uniqueidentifier

I'm trying to find a way to transform a large number of similar strings into unique hashes. The reason is that each string (an url), is used to generate a file on s3, for later access.

I need to be able to rebuild the hash at a later stage for comparison purposes.
I've used MD5 up until now, but some strings are long and very similar, which gave me duplicates.

I believe that a 256 or 512 hash would work, but maybe there's a best practice? I'd just use an URLencode as a filename, but one requirement is that a user wouldn't be able to access the base file on our server from the title of the S3 file.

Comment: Hmm, I had the same issue when I was trying to generate a unique stringtoken for Optimistic Concurrency Checking in some of my applications. So to prevent collisions, I also incorporated the DateTime of token generation down to a microsecond as part of the string MD5Encode. That really limit my collisions. Have you/Would you considered that?

Comment: yep timestamping was my first idea, but it won't work, because if the string appears again, I need to be able to reconstruct the hash to find out if I already have the file on s3